# Job failed with exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Unity Error

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I recently got this error:

> Job failed with exception:
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
> Insecure connection not allowed and this warning with it: Non-secure
> network connections disabled in Player Settings

This happens anytime I run the game build to android, force resolve, etc..

I am using Unity 2022.1.0b2 and have never gotten this error before.

I have been stuck on this problem for days now and cant find this fix, before that I got a message saying too many error when i build to android but i luckily found a fix by deleting the Plugins folder because it will be created again.

I use firebase database and authentication which when i build to android and put on google play the firebase just doesn't work and shows nothing (no leader-board and no sign-in/sign-up).
In the unity editor the firebase stuff works and is fine just not in the build.

I also use Unity ADS and Unity IAP, both work after build and in editor.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using a http connection. You have two options:

**1. Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings -> Configuration -> Allow downloads over HTTP set "Always allowed"**

**2. Wrap your http request in a try/catch block**

Think those two options will be the fix for most cases with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem. It turned out to be in my code where I forgot to use Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create(). I hope this helps someone who gets this same problem.

Comment: I have same error but not using firebase at all

Comment: @olucube.com look at my answer, could probalby fix your issue